# How can Retrieving Pending Transaction Reserves (reserve0 and reserve1) in Uniswap V2?

Tags: go-ethereum, uniswap, cpp-ethereum, uniswapv3, uniswapv2

How can I retrieve the reserve0 and reserve1 values from Uniswap V2, not from already mined blocks, but specifically from transactions that are still pending?